# Checkbox within a JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, swingx, jxtreetable

Still a Java newbie here, trying to stuff far too advanced for my own good.  Nevertheless, here's what I need done:  A checkbox within a JXTreeTable.  My main class:

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.production;

import info.chrismcgee.sky.production.treetable.NoRootTreeTableModel;

import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1899673458785493250L;
    private JXTreeTable treeTable;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 546, 600);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow][grow][100px:n,grow][grow][grow][grow]", "[][251.00,grow][]"));
        
        List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();
        
        List<ItemDetail> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
        itemList.add(new ItemDetail("N10", "N10", 2, 1000, PrintType.PAD, true));
        itemList.add(new ItemDetail("N13", "N13", 2, 2000, PrintType.PAD, true));
        
        // create and add the first job with its list of ItemDetail objects
        jobList.add(new Job(new Checkbox("Print Solutions"), "123456", ShipDate.getDate("02/28/14"), itemList));
        
        List<ItemDetail> itemList2 = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
        itemList2.add(new ItemDetail("P12", "Green", 1, 250, PrintType.SCREEN, true));
        itemList2.add(new ItemDetail("P12", "Purple", 1, 250, PrintType.SCREEN, true));
        itemList2.add(new ItemDetail("P12", "Gray", 1, 250, PrintType.SCREEN, true));
        
        // create and add a second job with its list of ItemDetail objects
        jobList.add(new Job(new Checkbox("Innovators Inc"), "246801", ShipDate.getDate("03/10/14"), itemList2));
        
        // we use a no root model
        NoRootTreeTableModel noRootTreeTableModel = new NoRootTreeTableModel(jobList);
        treeTable = new JXTreeTable(noRootTreeTableModel);
        treeTable.setEditable(false);
        treeTable.setRootVisible(false);
        treeTable.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        treeTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        treeTable.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
        treeTable.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(75);
        treeTable.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(15);
            treeTable.getColumn(2).setMinWidth(15);
            treeTable.getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(15);
        treeTable.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
            treeTable.getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(50);
        treeTable.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(25);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(treeTable);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, "cell 0 1 7 1,grow");

    }       
}
```

The Job class (Branches in the TreeTable):

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.production;

import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class Job {

    private Checkbox cbJob;
    private String idNumber;
    private LocalDate shipDate;
    private List<ItemDetail> itemList;
    
    public Job(Checkbox cbJob, String idNumber, LocalDate shipDate, List<ItemDetail> itemList)
    {
        this.cbJob = cbJob;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    public List<ItemDetail> getItemList()
    {
        return itemList;
    }
    
    public void setItemList(List<ItemDetail> itemList)
    {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the cbJob
     */
    public Checkbox getCbJob() {
        return cbJob;
    }

    /**
     * @param cbJob the cbJob to set
     */
    public void setCbJob(Checkbox cbJob) {
        this.cbJob = cbJob;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idNumber
     */
    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param idNumber the idNumber to set
     */
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the shipDate
     */
    public LocalDate getShipDate() {
        return shipDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param shipDate the shipDate to set
     */
    public void setShipDate(LocalDate shipDate) {
        this.shipDate = shipDate;
    }
    
}
```

The OrderDetail class (Leaves in the TreeTable):

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.production;


public class ItemDetail {

    private String productId;
    private String detail;
    private long numColors;
    private long numQuantity;
    private PrintType printType;
    private boolean active;
    
    public ItemDetail(String productId, String detail, long numColors, long numQuantity, PrintType printType, boolean active)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.detail = detail;
        this.numColors = numColors;
        this.numQuantity = numQuantity;
        this.printType = printType;
        this.active = active;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productId
     */
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    /**
     * @param productId the productId to set
     */
    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the detail
     */
    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    /**
     * @param detail the detail to set
     */
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numColors
     */
    public long getNumColors() {
        return numColors;
    }

    /**
     * @param numColors the numColors to set
     */
    public void setNumColors(long numColors) {
        this.numColors = numColors;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numQuantity
     */
    public long getNumQuantity() {
        return numQuantity;
    }

    /**
     * @param numQuantity the numQuantity to set
     */
    public void setNumQuantity(long numQuantity) {
        this.numQuantity = numQuantity;
    }

    /**
     * @return the printType
     */
    public PrintType getPrintType() {
        return printType;
    }

    /**
     * @param printType the printType to set
     */
    public void setPrintType(PrintType printType) {
        this.printType = printType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the active
     */
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    /**
     * @param active the active to set
     */
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

and, finally, the NoRootTreeTableModel class, which extends the AbstractTreeTableModel class, so that the root of the tree isn't shown:

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.production.treetable;

import info.chrismcgee.sky.production.ItemDetail;
import info.chrismcgee.sky.production.Job;

import java.util.List;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.AbstractTreeTableModel;

public class NoRootTreeTableModel extends AbstractTreeTableModel {
    
    private final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Name/Product", "Job # / Detail", "T",
        "Colors", "Quantity", "Total"};
    
    private List<Job> jobList;
    
    public NoRootTreeTableModel(List<Job> jobList)
    {
        super(new Object());
        this.jobList = jobList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
    {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(Object node, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node)
    {
        return node instanceof ItemDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if (parent instanceof Job) {
            Job job = (Job) parent;
            return job.getItemList().size();
        }
        return jobList.size();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if (parent instanceof Job) {
            Job job = (Job) parent;
            return job.getItemList().get(index);
        }
        return jobList.get(index);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        Job job = (Job) parent;
        ItemDetail item = (ItemDetail) child;
        return job.getItemList().indexOf(item);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(Object node, int column) {
        if (node instanceof Job) {
            Job job = (Job) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return job.getCbJob();
                case 1:
                    return job.getIdNumber();
            }
        } else if (node instanceof ItemDetail) {
            ItemDetail item = (ItemDetail) node;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return item.getProductId();
                case 1:
                    return item.getDetail();
                case 2:
                    return item.getPrintType();
                case 3:
                    return item.getNumColors();
                case 4:
                    return item.getNumQuantity();
                case 5:
                    return item.getNumColors() * item.getNumQuantity();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I know that is a lot of code, but I couldn't think of a quick way to cut it down and still have it work the way I need it to.  And actually, it's cut down quite a bit already.  (I left out a bunch of stuff that is normally also in that JFrame.)

When the code is run, I don't get a checkbox for the branches; instead, I get what appears to be a String representation of the checkbox code:
[image: Checkbox in a TreeTable]

Huh?  How did this happen and, more importantly, how can I get the checkbox to show up instead?

Answer (score 6):

You should never add components to a model, instead you should be providing a `TreeCellRenderer` to render the value of the node.  The Node is probably using the `toString` value of the user object assigned to it...

Take a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and [Customizing a Tree's Display](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) for more details

**Example Ripped Straight from [Customizing a Tree's Display](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display)**

[image: Check Boxes]

I'll leave it up to you create the editor and determine how the check box should get selected

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class TreeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

                    //Create and set up the window.
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GenealogyExample");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    //Create and set up the content pane.
                    GenealogyExample newContentPane = new GenealogyExample();
                    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
                    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

                    //Display the window.
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class GenealogyExample extends JPanel
            implements ActionListener {

        private JTree tree;
        private static String SHOW_ANCESTOR_CMD = "showAncestor";

        public GenealogyExample() {
            super(new BorderLayout());

            //Construct the panel with the toggle buttons.
            JRadioButton showDescendant
                    = new JRadioButton("Show descendants", true);
            final JRadioButton showAncestor
                    = new JRadioButton("Show ancestors");
            ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            bGroup.add(showDescendant);
            bGroup.add(showAncestor);
            showDescendant.addActionListener(this);
            showAncestor.addActionListener(this);
            showAncestor.setActionCommand(SHOW_ANCESTOR_CMD);
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.add(showDescendant);
            buttonPanel.add(showAncestor);

            //Construct the tree.
            tree = new JTree(new GenealogyModel(getGenealogyGraph()));
      tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
            tree.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxTreeCellRenderer());

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            //Add everything to this panel.
            add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        /**
         * Required by the ActionListener interface. Handle events on the
         * showDescendant and showAncestore buttons.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getActionCommand() == SHOW_ANCESTOR_CMD) {
                showAncestor(true);
            } else {
                showAncestor(false);
            }
        }

        public void showAncestor(boolean b) {
        Object newRoot = null;
        TreePath path = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectionPath();
        if (path != null) {
            newRoot = path.getLastPathComponent();
        }
        ((GenealogyModel)tree.getModel()).showAncestor(b, newRoot);
    }

        /**
         * Constructs the genealogy graph used by the model.
         */
        public Person getGenealogyGraph() {
            //the greatgrandparent generation
            Person a1 = new Person("Jack (great-granddaddy)");
            Person a2 = new Person("Jean (great-granny)");
            Person a3 = new Person("Albert (great-granddaddy)");
            Person a4 = new Person("Rae (great-granny)");
            Person a5 = new Person("Paul (great-granddaddy)");
            Person a6 = new Person("Josie (great-granny)");

            //the grandparent generation
            Person b1 = new Person("Peter (grandpa)");
            Person b2 = new Person("Zoe (grandma)");
            Person b3 = new Person("Simon (grandpa)");
            Person b4 = new Person("James (grandpa)");
            Person b5 = new Person("Bertha (grandma)");
            Person b6 = new Person("Veronica (grandma)");
            Person b7 = new Person("Anne (grandma)");
            Person b8 = new Person("Renee (grandma)");
            Person b9 = new Person("Joseph (grandpa)");

            //the parent generation
            Person c1 = new Person("Isabelle (mom)");
            Person c2 = new Person("Frank (dad)");
            Person c3 = new Person("Louis (dad)");
            Person c4 = new Person("Laurence (dad)");
            Person c5 = new Person("Valerie (mom)");
            Person c6 = new Person("Marie (mom)");
            Person c7 = new Person("Helen (mom)");
            Person c8 = new Person("Mark (dad)");
            Person c9 = new Person("Oliver (dad)");

            //the youngest generation
            Person d1 = new Person("Clement (boy)");
            Person d2 = new Person("Colin (boy)");

            Person.linkFamily(a1, a2, new Person[]{b1, b2, b3, b4});
            Person.linkFamily(a3, a4, new Person[]{b5, b6, b7});
            Person.linkFamily(a5, a6, new Person[]{b8, b9});
            Person.linkFamily(b3, b6, new Person[]{c1, c2, c3});
            Person.linkFamily(b4, b5, new Person[]{c4, c5, c6});
            Person.linkFamily(b8, b7, new Person[]{c7, c8, c9});
            Person.linkFamily(c4, c7, new Person[]{d1, d2});

            return a1;
        }

    }

    public static class CheckBoxTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

            cb.setText(value.toString());
            cb.setOpaque(selected);
            if (selected) {
                cb.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground"));
                cb.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground"));
            } else {
                cb.setBackground(tree.getBackground());
                cb.setForeground(tree.getForeground());
            }

            return cb;

        }

    } 

    public static class GenealogyModel implements TreeModel {

        private boolean showAncestors;
        private Vector<TreeModelListener> treeModelListeners
                = new Vector<TreeModelListener>();
        private Person rootPerson;

        public GenealogyModel(Person root) {
            showAncestors = false;
            rootPerson = root;
        }

        /**
         * Used to toggle between show ancestors/show descendant and to change the
         * root of the tree.
         */
        public void showAncestor(boolean b, Object newRoot) {
            showAncestors = b;
            Person oldRoot = rootPerson;
            if (newRoot != null) {
                rootPerson = (Person) newRoot;
            }
            fireTreeStructureChanged(oldRoot);
        }

//////////////// Fire events //////////////////////////////////////////////
        /**
         * The only event raised by this model is TreeStructureChanged with the root
         * as path, i.e. the whole tree has changed.
         */
        protected void fireTreeStructureChanged(Person oldRoot) {
            int len = treeModelListeners.size();
            TreeModelEvent e = new TreeModelEvent(this,
                    new Object[]{oldRoot});
            for (TreeModelListener tml : treeModelListeners) {
                tml.treeStructureChanged(e);
            }
        }

//////////////// TreeModel interface implementation ///////////////////////
        /**
         * Adds a listener for the TreeModelEvent posted after the tree changes.
         */
        public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
            treeModelListeners.addElement(l);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the child of parent at index index in the parent's child array.
         */
        public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
            Person p = (Person) parent;
            if (showAncestors) {
                if ((index > 0) && (p.getFather() != null)) {
                    return p.getMother();
                }
                return p.getFather();
            }
            return p.getChildAt(index);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of children of parent.
         */
        public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
            Person p = (Person) parent;
            if (showAncestors) {
                int count = 0;
                if (p.getFather() != null) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (p.getMother() != null) {
                    count++;
                }
                return count;
            }
            return p.getChildCount();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the index of child in parent.
         */
        public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
            Person p = (Person) parent;
            if (showAncestors) {
                int count = 0;
                Person father = p.getFather();
                if (father != null) {
                    count++;
                    if (father == child) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                if (p.getMother() != child) {
                    return count;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            return p.getIndexOfChild((Person) child);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the root of the tree.
         */
        public Object getRoot() {
            return rootPerson;
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if node is a leaf.
         */
        public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
            Person p = (Person) node;
            if (showAncestors) {
                return ((p.getFather() == null)
                        && (p.getMother() == null));
            }
            return p.getChildCount() == 0;
        }

        /**
         * Removes a listener previously added with addTreeModelListener().
         */
        public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
            treeModelListeners.removeElement(l);
        }

        /**
         * Messaged when the user has altered the value for the item identified by
         * path to newValue. Not used by this model.
         */
        public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
            System.out.println("*** valueForPathChanged : "
                    + path + " --> " + newValue);
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        Person father;
        Person mother;
        List<Person> children;
        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            mother = father = null;
            children = new ArrayList<Person>();
        }

        /**
         * Link together all members of a family.
         *
         * @param pa the father
         * @param ma the mother
         * @param kids the children
         */
        public static void linkFamily(Person pa,
                Person ma,
                Person[] kids) {
            for (Person kid : kids) {
                pa.children.add(kid);
                ma.children.add(kid);
                kid.father = pa;
                kid.mother = ma;
            }
        }

/// getter methods ///////////////////////////////////
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Person getFather() {
            return father;
        }

        public Person getMother() {
            return mother;
        }

        public int getChildCount() {
            return children.size();
        }

        public Person getChildAt(int i) {
            return (Person) children.get(i);
        }

        public int getIndexOfChild(Person kid) {
            return children.indexOf(kid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me how to utilize `TreeCellRenderer` to have the checkboxes show up in the treetable?  I'm sorry that I'm so clueless.

Comment: Cheka the links, try the examples

Comment: Yeah, I've read those links twice.  There's plenty of info about how to customize the look and feel of a tree, changing a node's icon, and setting tooltip text.  I don't see anything about having a Checkbox or other such item in a tree.

I would think this sort of thing should be somewhat common.  Even Windows has the capability to show checkboxes on all folders and files in Explorer, including in the folder tree.

Comment: There's an example which demonstrates the use of a `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` which changes the icon of the leaf node...this is where to start

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, MadProgrammer.  I appreciate your efforts, but I'm afraid they just aren't helping.  Perhaps I'm just too stupid, but I don't see where you "ripped" that code directly from a page that doesn't mention checkboxes once.  Yes, I see that I could possibly change the default icon of a tree node to a checkbox and, while that wasn't my original intention, it could work.

Comment: I also see that I would need to implement an Editor class so that events could be handled when the checkbox for each node is selected and deselected.  However, I am coming from a background of very little Java experience and even very little object-oriented programming experience, for that matter.  And it is extremely obvious that you don't have the time to walk me through your code so I can learn how to do what I need to do.  If you have a suggestion for a better place to get such help, please let me know.

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to be mean at all; I clearly just need more individual attention than you have time for.

Comment: You may want to take a look at editors and renders. With the exception of text components, JTree and JTable are the most complex components in a Swing and you are tackling a combination of both, personally, not a great place to start

Answer (score 3):

Sturm gives most of the solution.

The missing piece of the puzzle is that you can get the `JTree` from the `JXTreeTable` like this:

```
JTree tree = (JTree) treeTable.getCellRenderer(0, treeTable.getHierarchicalColumn())
```

It's a bit of a hack, but I don't know if they have any better API to get at it.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for a way to get access to the `JTree`. This probably saved me hours!

Answer (score 1):

With a few minutes of googling, I found this [CheckBox node tree sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm) and this [blog post about JXTreeTable with CheckBoxes](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jxtreetable_with_checkboxes), as well as this [very simple solution](http://huionn.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/jxtreetable-with-checkbox/).

Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: DuncanKinnear, thank you for your links, but it is still not exactly what I am looking for.  The closest is your last link, to huionn's blog post.  When I posted the bounty, I specifically asked for some personalized, 1-on-1, step-by-step help on making this work in my specific situation, as that is how I learn best.  Not by just being thrown a set of links and told "you should have been able to find these yourself".  I realize I'm asking for a lot, and I'm about to go crazy because I haven't yet found a good person to hand-hold me through this problem.