# trying to align JcheckBox in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, jcheckbox

I'm working with `GridBagLayout` and I can't figure why the `JCheckBox` don't align. I've tried to set alignement as a `JCheckBox` parameter(i.e `checkBox.setAlignementX(LEFT_ALIGNEMENT)`). It did'nt worked.

I first tried using `BorderLayout`, but it turned out even worst

What I'm trying to acheive is this[image]

I want the threee main categories(Physique, Psychologique and Social) to be set on the complete left, and i want the sub-categories to be set just a bit offset. That way you'll know it's a sub-categorie(according to the lines i've drawn).

There uis three `JPanel`, one for each category. 
This is not the original code but it somewhat reproduce the problem i have.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
private JButton button = new JButton("Generer");
private JCheckBox physique = new JCheckBox("Traits Physiques");
private JCheckBox psychologic = new JCheckBox("Traits Psychologiques");
private JCheckBox mass = new JCheckBox("Masse");
private JCheckBox quality = new JCheckBox("Qualité");
private JTextArea text = new JTextArea("");
private JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public Window() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTitle("Personnage");
    setSize(500, 350);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    text.setEditable(false);
    arrange();
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * Arrange all the layout
 */
private void arrange() {
    JPanel phPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel psPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbcPanel, gbcPh, gbcPs;
    gbcPanel = gbcPh = gbcPs = new GridBagConstraints();

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbcPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbcPanel.gridy = 0;
        gbcPanel.gridheight = 1;
        gbcPanel.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(phPanel, gbcPanel);
        gbcPanel.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(psPanel, gbcPanel);
    //---------------------------
        gbcPh.gridx = 0;
        gbcPh.gridy = 0;
        gbcPh.gridheight = 1;
        gbcPh.gridwidth = 2;
    phPanel.add(physique, gbcPh);
        gbcPh.gridx = 1;
        gbcPh.gridy = 1;
        gbcPh.gridwidth = 1;
    phPanel.add(mass, gbcPh);
    //--------------------------
        gbcPs.gridx = 0;
        gbcPs.gridy = 0;
        gbcPs.gridheight = 1;
        gbcPs.gridwidth = 2;
    psPanel.add(psychologic, gbcPs);
        gbcPs.gridx = 1;
        gbcPs.gridy = 1;
        gbcPs.gridwidth = 1;
    psPanel.add(quality, gbcPs);
    //------------------------

}
```

}

I want the main category(i.e physique and psychologic) to be align totally left and the sub category(i.e mass and quality) to be a bit offset. I can't do that, i don't know how, i've read multiple tutorial etc...

[The original code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52559258/Java%20Code.txt)

Comment: I'm not sure that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll try to explain better what i'm trying to acheive.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels There you go. Is it better explained?

Comment: Chax, please have a look at the link I've provided in my first comment. Please comment back to me and let me know if you post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I'll take a look at it. Remember that this program needs to be short, very short, compilable, runnable, not require outside resources (unless they're easily obtainable from the internet) and shows for us your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels There you go. A simplified code that have my problems in it. Plus it is compilable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, `setAlignmentX` probably isn't going to do much for your, `setHorizontalAlignment` would be a better choice, but having said that, there are other things you can do with the `GridBagConstraints`

To start with, you could use the `anchor` and `weightx` properties...

```
phyConstraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
phyConstraint.weightx = 1;
```

The anchor will determine the position within the given cell the component will want to align to, this defaults to `CENTER`.  The `weightx` property describes the amount of space that will given to, based on the remaining space left over after the layout has been calculated, in this case, we're asking for all the remaining space.

Next, you can use the `insets` properties to determine the amount of internal spacing or margin a cell will have, this will affect the position the component when it's laid out...

```
phyConstraint.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 0, 0);
```

Finally, for the `optionConstraint`, we can also use the `fill` property, which will determine how a component will size depending on the amount of available space within there cell, in this case, you'll want the component to expand to fill all the available space, for example...

```
optionConstraint.weightx = 1;
optionConstraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

[image: Layout]

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

I'd also consider having a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), which might save you some trouble...

Comment: What is the big difference between `GridBagLayout` and `Trees`?

Comment: @Chax A `JTree` is designed to do what you are trying to do, it's much easier to update and modify (add new elements) and allows you to even collapse and expand branches

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll have a look at that. Plus your answer is really good. It is well explained.

Comment: @Chax: as per usual. All his answers are like that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Over the top, long winded, rants of little to no relevance, until you get to the example code at the end ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yeah, that's the truth, but I didn't have the heart to say that to your face. Sorry.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, I'm like that grandparent who you had to sit and listen to for hours on end, only because you knew you'd get a few bucks or sweets from them at the end ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Have you ever tought of being a teacher or something like that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer any idea on how to add checkbox to a `JTree`? All the solution i found are either inappropriate for my problem or over-hardcore for my skills...

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924846/checkbox-within-a-jxtreetable/21924930#21924930) for example, about as ease it will get...don't be scared to grow your mad skills

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not scared, I still a bit lost in the `JTree` ;)

Comment: `JTree` is among the most complex of components, so I'm not surprised, but if you can deal with it (and `JTable`), you'll be able to deal with just about anything

Comment: @Mad It's a good news...i guess :P