# How can I add checkbox in tree table

Tags: java, swing, multiple-columns, jtree, jtreetable

I want to created a `Tree` with multi-columns. I found this tutorial [here](http://www.hameister.org/JavaSwingTreeTable.html) (German) and this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) (English). I want to add checkboxes in one column, but I have no idea how to do it. When I return a checkbox to `JTreeTable`, something show in execute is checkbox detail not checkbox object. How can I get something like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), pictured below?

[image: like that]

Comment: Isnt `JCheckBox` is displayed as default for `boolean` data of a `JTable` cell?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924846/checkbox-within-a-jxtreetable/21924930#21924930), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375773/how-do-you-make-components-of-jpanel-as-a-node-in-jtree-usable/31376208#31376208) and personally, I'd use `JXTreeTable` from SwingX, it's simply a better implementation which will give you the control you will need to make this work

Comment: thanks,i dont want let the checkboxes inside Jtrees, i want to do is in the column besides trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in *[Taking the New Swing Tree Table for a Spin](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-)*, cited [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), your implementation of [`RowModel`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/RowModel.html) must return the correct type from `getColumnClass()` and the correct value from `getValueFor()`. Values of type `Boolean.class` will be rendered with a `JCheckBox`. The following implementations produce the image cited:

[image]

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return Date.class;
        case 1:
            return Long.class;
        case 2:
            return Boolean.class;
        case 3:
            return Boolean.class;
        case 4:
            return Boolean.class;
        default:
            assert false;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getValueFor(Object node, int column) {
    File f = (File) node;
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return new Date(f.lastModified());
        case 1:
            return f.length();
        case 2:
            return f.canRead();
        case 3:
            return f.canWrite();
        case 4:
            return f.canExecute();
        default:
            assert false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

> I can't select checkbox.

You need to return `true` in your implementation of `isCellEditable()` for the desired column(s) and update the `node` in your implementation of `setValueFor()` accordingly. When the cell editor concludes, your implementation of `setValueFor()` will be called, so verify that it updates the *same* value that will later be returned by `getValueFor()`. Optionally, you'll want to implement the `TreeModel` methods that manage the `TreeModelListener` list by using the scheme prescribed in an [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) API; the [`DefaultTreeModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) source [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.java) is a good example.

Comment: thank you,i add checkbox into table successful, it seems  i dont need to create new JCheckbox objects,it use default JCheckbox,can i use my customize checkbox?

Comment: and i cant select checkbox

Comment: The example cited uses `File`, instances of which are immutable; I've elaborated above on the general approach to handling mutable data.

Comment: can I use my custom checkbox?   default is JCheckbox

Comment: Yes; use `setDefaultEditor()`; ping me here if you pose a new question on this topic.

Comment: I return the custom Checkbox in `getTableCellEditorComponent` and `getTableCellRendererComponent` but it didn`
t work

Comment: I'm not sure what didn't work; I see the expected result using `DefaultCellEditor` with `JCheckBox`; if you're still having trouble; please post a new question with a [mcve] that shows your approach.