# checkbox renderer incorrect in JTable's column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I successful add checkbox into JTable's column. but I want to use my custom checkbox, i modified BooleanRender to extend my custom checkbox , and it works.the problem is when I selected the checkbox it will show default jCheckbox design at moment and show my coustom checkbox, it also happen when i unselected the checkbox.
[here is the question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471989/how-can-i-add-checkbox-in-tree-table/36478993?noredirect=1#comment60786693_36478993)

```
class  BooleanRenderer extends TriCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer, UIResource {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final Border noFocusBorder = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

BooleanRenderer() {
    super();
    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    setBorderPainted(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    setSelected(value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
    if (hasFocus) {
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
    } else {
        setBorder(noFocusBorder);
    }
    return this;
}
```

}

```
public class TriCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
public static ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon("src/checkbox_off.png");
public static ImageIcon smallIcon = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance (12, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
public static ImageIcon iconDark =new ImageIcon("src/logo.png");
public static ImageIcon smallIconDark = new ImageIcon(iconDark.getImage().getScaledInstance (12, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
public static ImageIcon iconBrown =new ImageIcon("src/checkbox_on.png");
public static ImageIcon smallIconBrown = new ImageIcon(iconBrown.getImage().getScaledInstance (12, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
private boolean indeterminate;
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (isSelected()) {
        indeterminate = false;
    }
    if(indeterminate){
        setIcon(smallIconDark);
    }else if(isSelected()){
        setIcon(smallIconBrown);
    }else{
        setIcon(smallIcon);
    }
    super.paint(g);
}
public boolean isIndetermainate() {
    return indeterminate;
}
public void setIndetermainate(boolean indetermainate) {
    this.indeterminate = indetermainate;
    if (indetermainate) {
        setSelected(false);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `public static ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon("src/checkbox_off.png");` 3) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 4) Using `static` more often causes problems, than solves them. Remove all the `static` modifiers before posting that MCVE (mentioned & linked above).

Answer (score 2):

First, it is not a good idea to override the `paint(...)` method, if you want to do some painting, override the `paintComponent(...)` method instead.

In this case, you're not doing any custom painting so you don't need to override any of these methods. Here is what you can do instead:

```
public class TriCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
    ....

    public void updateState() {
        if (isSelected()) {
            indeterminate = false;
        }
        if(indeterminate){
            setIcon(smallIconDark);
        }else if(isSelected()){
            setIcon(smallIconBrown);
        }else{
            setIcon(smallIcon);
        }
    }

    public void setIndetermainate(boolean indetermainate) {
        this.indeterminate = indetermainate;
        if (indetermainate) {
            setSelected(false);        
        }else{
            updateState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        updateState();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at `public void updateState(Graphics g) {`, because I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've copied the OP's `paint(....)` method and forgot to remove that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> problem is when I selected the checkbox it will show default jCheckbox design at moment and show my coustom checkbox, it also happen when i unselected the checkbox.

Start by taking a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Just like the fact that you had to provide a custom `TableCellRenderer`, you're going to have to provide a custom `TableCellEditor`

Then adding to what @Titus has suggested, you should not be referencing `src` in your paths

```
public static ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon("src/checkbox_off.png");
```

needs to become

```
public static ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon(TriCheckBox.class.getResource("/checkbox_off.png"));
```